# Equality of arrays with reference and type members in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have a class named `Person` and two arrays that contain value and reference type members. I want to check these arrays for equality:

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

var firstPerson = Person("John")
var secondPerson = Person("James")
var firstArray = ["firstWord", firstPerson, 12]
var secondArray = ["firstWord", secondPerson, 12]
print(firstArray == secondArray)
```

How does Swift compiler will compare these arrays?

- Will it check first members of arrays (`"firstWord"`) for equality and then will check second members (`firstPerson` and `secondPerson`) for identity?
- If so, do I need to conform the `Equatable` protocol for the `Person` classes in the following code:

By the way, why does `==` function has to be declared outside of the `Person` class in order to work properly?

```
func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    let areEqual = lhs.name == rhs.name
    return areEqual
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not 100% sure about this. Should you find some errors please let me know.

First of all this does not compile

```
var firstPerson = Person("John")
var secondPerson = Person("James")
```

and it should be

```
var firstPerson = Person(name: "John")
var secondPerson = Person(name: "James")
```

### How will Swift compare these arrays?

`firstArray` and `secondArray` are inferred to be `NSArray` because you are putting different kind of values into them and your are not explicitly declaring them as `[Any]`.

When you write `firstArray == secondArray` the code is bridged to Objective-C this way

```
firstArray.isEqualToArray(secondArray as [AnyObject])
```

The `isEqualToArray` method checks for equality every element.

### [0]

```
"firstWord" == "firstWord"
```

is converted to

```
("firstWord" as NSString).isEqual("firstWord" as NSString)
```

and is `true`.

### [1]

Both arrays reference the same `Person` object so it's `true`

### [2]

```
12 == 12
```

is converted to

```
(12 as NSNumber).isEqual(NSNumber(int: 12))
```

which is `true`.

### Recap

So the result of the array comparation is `true`.

### What does happen if the arrays are declared as [Any]?

In this case there is no Objective-C bridging.
In Swift we can check equality of 2 arrays if the related type is `Equatable`. Since `Any` is NOT `Equatable` we'll get a compiler error.

```
firstArray == secondArray
Binary operator `==` cannot be applied to two [Any] operands
```

Comment: Great explanation. Could you expand your answer to explain what happens if the array is typed `[Any]`?

Comment: @AaronBrager: Thank you. I added the explanation for `[Any]`